# JavaScript: get a value with jQuery and replace it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, label

I have a gender selector, and a script that gets the value of the selected gender and pastes it on a label, but it's pasting the value: "M" or "F".

```
<div name="userLabelDiv" id="genderUserLabelDiv">
    <label class="required">Sexo</label>    
    <label id="genderLabel">F</label> 
</div>
```

Now when I'm trying to get this letter and replace for the actual gender, I'm missing on the JS script. Could you help me?

```
$("#genderLabel").html(
    if ($(this).value == 'F') {
        this.value = 'Female';
    }
    if ($(this).value == 'M') {
        this.value = 'Male';
    }
);
```

I know the script is probably wrong, could someone correct it, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery 1.4+ you can pass a function to [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) like this:

```
$("#genderLabel").text(function(i, t) {
   return t == 'F' ? 'Female' : t == 'M' ? 'Male' : t;
});
```

This converts `F` to `Female`, `M` to `Male` and leaves anything else alone, in case new genders come up :)

Comment: SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression { message="missing : in conditional expression",  more...}

Comment: @BoDiE2003 - woops typo, fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var gender = $('#genderLabel');
if (gender.text() == 'F') { gender.text('Female'); }
else { gender.text('Male'); }
```

Comment: This code, is giving me syntax errors:

$("[name=userDto\\.gender]").change(function() { 
  if ($(this).text() == 'F') {
    $(this).text('Femenino'); 
  } else { 
    $(this).text('Masculino'); 
  } 
});

Answer (score 2):

replace every `value` with `text()`

```
if($(this).text()=='F'){
   $(this).text('Female');
}
if($(this).text()=='M'){
    $(this).text('Male');
}
```

Among a few other things

Answer (score 1):

To use `.html()` that way, you need to pass a `function` as the argument that returns the value you want.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/FDZBJ/

```
$("#genderLabel").html(function(i,html) {
                           html = $.trim(html);
                           if(html == 'F') return 'Female';
                           if(html == 'M') return 'Male';
                           return html;
                       });
```